# Magento 2: How to refresh payment method on some condition

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, ajax

Like I have applied a checkbox on payment page for using it as credit score inspite of money. There is problem when my credit is 100 % used i.e. by using credit score grand total becomes 0. In that case Zero checkout payment should come but its not coming and when i reload the page that zero checkout payment method comes is there any way to refresh payment method list on my checkbox click. You can check in below image what i am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Can describe using which method you added checkbox there in payment section?

Comment: its done by overriding , checkout_index_index.xml and then put your  js and html to show checkbox

Comment: Can you please share your full code here, I have same requirement.

Answer (score 5):

you can use some code like this:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
     'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information'
], function (Component,quote,ko , jQuery, getTotalsAction, fullScreenLoader,getPaymentInformationAction) {
    'use strict';

    // some code

     return Component.extend({
        //some code
        reloadPayment: function() {
            var self = this;

            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
            jQuery.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        checked: self.creditValue(),
                        quote_id: quoteId
                     },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response) {
                            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
                            getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                            // var deferred = $.Deferred();
                             fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                            getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                            jQuery.when(deferred).done(function () {
                                isApplied(false);
                                totals.isLoading(false);
                            });
                            messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                                'message': message
                            });
                           totals.isLoading(true);


                        }
                    }
            });
           return true;
        } 

    });
});
```

in this code, I'm reloading the payment method when ajax request is succeeded.

Main part of the code for reloading payment info:

```
getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
jQuery.when(deferred).done(function () {
    isApplied(false);
    totals.isLoading(false);
});
```

Comment: welcome buddy :-)

Comment: Below js was not working for me ...can u hlep me

Comment: I have refresh the payment section as per your code, But I wish to unset the selected paymnet method before refreshing payment section

Comment: I have tried quote.setPaymnetMethod(null) . It unsets the selected paymnet section, but  after refreshing payment section it sets the selected paymnet method again. Please provide me a solution

Comment: `totals` is undefined . Who is `totals` ?