# Magento 2: How can i reload section payment Method in checkout page?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, magento-2.2.5

how can i reload Payment Method section in checkout page?
I create a custom discount. when i set custom discount and apply, i need reload total section and payment section. I use this code:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
getTotalsAction([], deferred);
getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);

$.when(deferred).done(function () {
    paymentService.setPaymentMethods(
        paymentMethodList()
    );
});
```

i set custom discount and grand total = 0, but just only total section reload again and show correct, payment method is not reload and not show "no payment required", its still show another payment. ? Can Anyone help me? Or Am I missing something?
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with your related js file `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/discount.js`

Checkout given blow link it might be help to solve your problem.

1. [magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160479](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/magento-2-how-to-refresh-payment-method-on-some-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [stackoverflow.com/questions/41340262](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340262/magento2-apply-coupon-code-button-at-checkout-payment-step-after-refresh)

I hope it will help to you.

Comment: no, its not my problem, totals section reload is fine but payment reload not change, i try to use both link, but its now working

Comment: Ok, nop have you got any other solution?

Comment: no, still find solution for this

Comment: HI @Init, Have you tried with fresh magento bcz its working fine with fresh installation.  Please check video https://www.loom.com/share/92433ac5a66145d89a15e925b9456720